# Top Ubuntu Download Manager with bandwidth limiter and

Tags: firefox, download-speed, uget

I need to have some limitation on file downloading because of my low is speed downloading, so I installed your Get into my Ubuntu, which has a bandwidth limitation, but my problem is the agent doesn't have good Firefox add-ons. I prefer to use the *Download them all* extensions of Firefox, because of its higher number of options, but I also prefer to have downloaded in separate software for Firefox because of crashing my Firefox for some reason (opening too many tabs and...).

How could it be done better? Is there any alternative to get? (I have installed [XDM Download Manager](https://itsfoss.com/xtreme-download-manager-install/) also in my Ubuntu, but it doesn't start in my Ubuntu as ***you can see*** here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will be surprised by what you can achieve in command line in linux.

Install aria2 and have look at the man pages. There is basically nothing it cannot do that any other GUI based download manager can.

`sudo apt install aria2`

Comment: And uGet is a nice GUI frontend for `aria2`, if you want that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JDownloader. It's a download manager written in Java. JDownloader can download normal files, as well as from online file hosting services like mega.nz. You can set bandwidth limits it also has a good firefox addon. You can also remote control the downloads.
http://jdownloader.org/download/index

Also, there is another downloader manager called Persepolis. It is a download manager and a GUI For `aria2`. It's written in Python. If using aria2 from terminal does not look intuitive, you can use Persepolis. https://persepolisdm.github.io/